# How to get data from an input text in a jsp page in order to insert it into database?

Tags: database, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm new with  *spring Mvc* and I'm blocked in retrieving data from my `input text` in my `jsp page` .

I want to retrieve user data from the form in order to insert it into database using a simple `JDBC`connection  and making sure that the user doesn't exist into database.

Maybe my code will explain the problem better:

This is the controller responsible of retrieving data and insert it into data base :

```
   @Controller()
   public class AddController  {

    @Inject
    @Named(value = "dataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource1;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addDB", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public void Add(){


        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        Connection connection = null;

        String insert = "insert into user values(?,?,?,?)";

        try {
            connection = dataSource1.getConnection();
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(insert);
            preparedStatement.setString(1,//what to write here );
            preparedStatement.setString(2,***);
            preparedStatement.setString(3,***);
            preparedStatement.setString(4,***); 
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

 }
 }
```

and here is my jsp page :

```
 <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
 <c:url value="/addDB" var="addUrl" />

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
      $(function() {

    $('#add').click(function() {
        $.get('${addUrl}');
    });
});
</script>
 </head>
<body>
        <form>
                <fieldset style="width: 472px;">
                    <legend>Add user </legend>

                    <div>

                        <p>
                            <label>num</label> <input name="num" type="text" />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div>

                        <p>
                            <label>name</label> <input name="name" type="text" />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div>

                        <p>
                            <label>phone</label> <input name="phone" type="text" />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div>

                        <p>
                            <label>age</label> <input name="age" type="text" />
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div align="center">
                        <p>
                            <button class="button" type="button" value="add">add
                            </button>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>

 </body>
```

Is my work correct ? Is there something missing ? 
Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Have u tried to run ur application?

Comment: yes I have run it ..when I click on the button ,nothing is  inserted into DB ..

Answer (score 0):

Since SpringMVC has three layers (Model, View, Controller) you should not include SQL code in your controller. Try creating a DAO class for each persistent class in your project. Your DAO class will has, at least, the insert, update, delete and list methods. Then all you have to do is using the dao clases in your controllers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Lorena , but a DAO class isn't related to Hibernate ? Because I found many tutorials using DAO classes with Hibernate ..and in my application I'm using Oracle database with a simple JDBC connection ?